# Odd uneditable text in a question

Tags: support

[asm in C "too many memory references for `mov'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15035379/asm-in-c-too-many-memory-references-for-mov)

This question has some odd text at the end that looks like a comment. When I try to edit it out, it doesn't appear in the editable text. Is this something added by the SO engine? And why is it repeated so many times?

Comment: I see nothing wrong--are you talking about the part where it was mostly code but now it isn't?

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes. It looks like someone else edited it. Perhaps they did it right as I clicked the edit link myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like [someone edited it already](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15035379/revisions), and maybe there was a clash there.

The user repeated it because they were getting that very message when trying to post their question, because it was pretty much just the code. So they spammed that text in there to get around that automated quality control mechanism. (You were definitely right to want to edit it out)

Comment: That was my guess, but I was confused when I tried to edit and it wasn't there. Maybe someone else beat me to it just as I clicked the edit link /shrugs

Comment: @Code-Guru Yup; that's my guess - you hit 'edit' just after David had just edited it.

Comment: Cool. `Your comment could not be submitted; please add some more details.Your comment could not be submitted; please add some more details.Your comment could not be submitted; please add some more details.Your comment could not be submitted; please add some more details.Your comment could not be submitted; please add some more details.Your comment could not be submitted; please add some more details.Your comment could not be submitted; please add some more details.Your comment could not be submitted; please add some more details.`

Comment: @WesleyMurch Ooh, I get to use the "too chatty" comment flag! :p